# How to remove an overlay iframe appear on every sites - Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I just download a torrent file and suddenly i can't click on any sites. I try to inspect element and find out there is a iframe that stay over any site content that i open using chrome:

```
    <iframe id="vpnOfferFrame" src="//service.securesrv12.com/servicejs/components/vpnframe/?domain=subscene.com" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; z-index: 2147483647;">
</iframe>
```

Manually delete this iframe, i can click again but it appears on any site and on a reload. I try delete and reinstall chrome and reset settings but none working. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Install anti-virus software and scan your PC. it's also worth installing a malware-specific scanner as CCleaner.
(https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)